# Which weapon gains experience when downing an enemy in CoD Warzone?

Tags: call-of-duty-warzone

If you down an enemy with one weapon and finish them with a different weapon, which weapon gains the xp?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it is the weapon that you finish them with, as my X16 has gained quite a few levels from finishing enemies in the early game to conserve ammo.